# How can I add to Mobirise's project pop-up window in the left bottom corner?

Tags: html, css, mobirise

I want to add to the site, which I've created in Mobirise bootstrap builder a popping out window, so my customers could contact me any time they want. not looking for form on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Mobirise builder is really awesome but it doesn't have enough options. You can add  to code editor this https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm
The location of this window would depend upon the code. Could you please show it here.